# Flatlist TouchableHighlight passing value

Tags: javascript, react-native

i wanna implement a page able to list some categories and once clicked, do some other tasks.
I've tried to implement it like I'm doing here but when I render the page, category is automatic chosen and it is set to last value.
What i wrong?
Here my code

```js
const data = [
      {category: 'a'},
      {category: 'b'},
      {category: 'c'},
    ];
    
 <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={categoryStyles.itemContainer}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={{ }} selectedCategory={item.category} 
            onPress={this._nextStep(item.category)}>
                <View style={{alignItems:'center', justifyContent: 'space-around',}}>
                  <Icon name={item.icon} size={40}/>
                  <Text style={categoryStyles.item}>{item.description}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          numColumns={numColumns} />
          
          
 _nextStep = (selectedCategory) => {
    if (this.state.index !== this.props.children.length - 1) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        index: prevState.index + 1,
      }));
      this.setState(() => ({
        selectedCategory: selectedCategory,
      }));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change this

```
 onPress={this._nextStep(item.category)}
```

To

```
 onPress={()=> this._nextStep(item.category)}
```